# How to find meta tag source?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I have a site where the conditional,

```
<!--[if IE]><![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

shows in the header, but I can't figure out where it's coming from. I've checked the template.php, .htaccess, html.tpl.php, common.inc, an everywhere else i can think of.  Any ideas of where this is hiding, or how I can find it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What theme are you using

Comment: @PatrickRyan I'm using the a theme called dawn

Answer (score 0):

I was going to check the theme for you but it looks like that's a private theme so I'll try to outline some other places you can check.

The most common places you would find it are `html.tpl.php` and `template.php` but it sounds like you've covered those.  If it's not in `html.tpl.php` then it is likely being added with `drupal_add_html_head()`.

Other places to look outside of the ones you've already checked could be in your `/modules` folder - looking for any custom modules that came with the theme.  If the tag is being added with `drupal_add_html_head()` then it could be in a custom module.

If not in `template.php`, check if the theme uses individual files for preprocess functions.  ie look for `html.preprocess.inc` or something similar.

The theme might have some `*.inc` files for random features - you can check those as well.

A quick grep of your theme folder for `drupal_add_html_head` or `X-UA-Compatible` would likely get you your answer quickly.

Comment: All of the preprocess is all being done in the template.php file. I've searched every other file in the theme folder, with no hits for "X-UA-Compatible", or "drupal_add_html_head".

Comment: Try the last option and grep the entire theme folder that you purchased, it will certainly show up.  There is grep for windows if you don't have access to linux.

Answer (score 0):

Grep your codebase for [`drupal_add_html_head()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) calls or "X-UA-Compatible" text. This can be inside any module. If you still don't find it, and you have the PHP filter module enabled, you might need to search the `field_data_body` table for calls in PHP code stored in the DB.